# hosts file (Windows) works incorrectly in some browsers

Tags: hosts

When i add this to hosts file:
  `192.168.1.10 example.com`
Google Chrome works as expected and opens page at 192.168.1.10.
Ping shows correct ip address.
However Firefox and another Chromium-based browser is unable to connect.

Comment: I don't have this problem unless I forget to restart the browsers completely.  They cache DNS.

Comment: even tried rebooting